# Custom Marker In Google Maps not Showing in Samsung S8 or same version 7.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I am a new Android Developer. I am creating google map and custom marker with lat long map and markers work and show proper in S4 mobile but not shown in s8 or higher version mobile I grant all permission for that.I also put click listener on Custom Marker. These all work fine in s4 or low version mobile but not work in high version api  mobile. Thanks in Advance..
 where i am wrong ? please help me
 Here is my code

```
public void mSetUpMap() {
googleMap.clear();
/**Create dummy Markers List*/
List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
for (City item :  cityList)
{

if (googleMap !=null) {
 Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
   LatLng(item.getLatitude(), 
   item.getLongitude())).title(item.getName()).anchor(0.5f, 
   0.5f).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker(
   item.getDrawableId(), item.getName()))));
            markersList.add(m1);
        }

    }
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1); //change for 
           (0,1) if you want a fade in
            ani.setDuration(2000);
            ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
              {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }

            });
            ani.start();
            if(marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(0).getName()))
            {
                AppUtil.city=cityList.get(0);

            }
            else if(marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(1).getName()))
            {
                AppUtil.city=cityList.get(1);

            }
            else if(marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(2).getName()))
            {
                AppUtil.city=cityList.get(2);

            }
            else if(marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(3).getName()))
            {
                AppUtil.city=cityList.get(3);

            }
            else if(marker.getTitle().equals(cityList.get(4).getName()))
            {
                AppUtil.city=cityList.get(4);

            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new 
            CityDetailFragment());
            transaction.commit();
            /*((CityDetailFragment) adapter.getItem(1)).setupData();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,false);*/
            return true;
        }
     });

     /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
        builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    /**initialize the padding for map boundary*/
    final int padding = 150;
    /**create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera*/
    final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    /**create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map*/
    cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    /**call the map call back to know map is loaded or not*/
   enter code here


     googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 
            padding));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap createStoreMarker() {
    ViewGroup continer = null;


    View markerLayout = view.inflate(null, 
    R.layout.store_marker_layout,continer);



    markerLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, 
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, 
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), 
    markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    final Bitmap bitmap = 
     Bitmap.createBitmap(markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), 
    markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    markerLayout.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```